# Convert pdf file to html file in JavaScript/jquery on client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

Is there a way to convert a pdf file into html file using JavaScript or jquery? Can this be done on client side and run locally?

So far I have only found server side solutions  like pdf2htmlEX

Maybe there is library?

Answer (score 2):

Only in nodejs I think.  You can run

```
npm install pdftohtmljs
```

Then in your server code:

```
var pdftohtml = require('pdftohtmljs');
var converter = new pdftohtml('file.pdf', "file.html");

// see https://github.com/fagbokforlaget/pdftohtmljs/blob/master/lib/presets/ipad.js 
converter.convert('ipad').then(function() {
  console.log("converted");
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Alternatively, use [this software](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdftohtmljs) which is easy to use from the command line.

Comment: I'm trying to do this client side without server side code. I know there are server side implementations out there

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is possible at this moment. Perhaps PDF.js by Mozilla can get you in the right direction:

> https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

and the github repo

> https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Comment: Yes I tried using this but it renders html to browser and server is needed so I could not get the html elements in a file